# flutter getx initialroute delay

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx.

I want to add a delay to the initialRoute of GetMatrialApp.

initialRoute : splash screen

I want to stay on splashscrren for 2-3 seconds and then go to the login screen.

There is no delay even if you put a delay function in the splashscreen's init function.

init function :

```
  void initState() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
      await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => loginScreen()));
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: And what happens after the code shared? Open loginScreen instantly?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Even if you apply the code you posted, there is no delay.

Comment: Hi could you try adding your code into the top of the `build()` method instead of the `initState()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
  await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => loginScreen()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The process of manually entering this time when the program starts is very tedious. I would advise you to use the splashscreen package.
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen)